# How to drop the rows if two columns cells are empty?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

This is my DF

```
A  B  C
1  10 10
2  
3  12 12
4      
5  21 22
```

i want to compare the columns B and C then i have to check both are null after that i want to remove that rows from DF.

Output looks like,this

```
A  B  C
1  10 10
3  12 12     
5  21 22
```

Then i need to check again both columns of B and C like whether the values or same or not , if same i need to create one column say validation_results and print Y and if not same print N.

```
A  B  C  Validation_Results
1  10 10  Y
3  12 12  Y  
5  21 22  N
```

I am new to python so anybody here tell me how can i do this with minimum lines of code.

Comment: Yeah ! i don't know why it closed whats wrong in that question.

Comment: It's likely that posting a set of requirements without showing your own effort to solve the problem is the problem

Comment: This is exactly the same as your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59264306/7851470). Why post it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution if no values are missing values:

Use [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) new column created by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
print (df)
   A     B     C
0  1  10.0  10.0
1  2   NaN   NaN
2  3  12.0  12.0
3  4   NaN   NaN
4  5  21.0  22.0

df1 = (df.dropna(subset=['B','C'], how='all')
         .assign(Validation_Results = lambda x: np.where(x.B==x.C, 'Y', 'N')))
print (df1)
   A     B     C Validation_Results
0  1  10.0  10.0                  Y
2  3  12.0  12.0                  Y
4  5  21.0  22.0                  N
```

Solution if no values are empty strings:

```
print (df)
   A   B   C
0  1  10  10
1  2        
2  3  12  12
3  4        
4  5  21  22

df1 = (df[df[['B','C']].ne('').all(axis=1)]
         .assign(Validation_Results = lambda x: np.where(x.B==x.C, 'Y', 'N')))
print (df1)
   A   B   C Validation_Results
0  1  10  10                  Y
2  3  12  12                  Y
4  5  21  22                  N
```

**Details**:

First compare both columns by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) for not equal `''` - empty string:

```
print (df[['B','C']].ne(''))
       B      C
0   True   True
1  False  False
2   True   True
3  False  False
4   True   True
```

And then test if both values in row are `True`s by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
print (df[['B','C']].ne('').all(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

And filter them by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df[df[['B','C']].ne('').all(axis=1)])
   A   B   C
0  1  10  10
2  3  12  12
4  5  21  22
```

Comment: I tried this code but it doesn't drop the rows.Sorry about that.It will check for the null values only right.After assign lambda exprxns are working fine.

Comment: @user11646543 - Can you check now?

Comment: Yeah now its working, Will you please tell me what is the difference b/w the 1st code and second code and what is that .ne() method purpose?

Comment: @user11646543 - Answer was edited.

Comment: Nice to see a useful application of np.where finally :)